# On bitbucket newly created git branch does not show in active or merged branch list

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

My main branch is master.

I ran below commands:

```
git checkout develop

git branch feature/profile

git checkout feature/profile

git pull origin develop
```

I have created this new branch but I have to merge my named branch say "abc" to "feature/profile" but on bitbucket feature/profile does not exist.

If I run

```
git branch -a
```

I see:

```
*develop
feature/profile
abc
master
...
...
```

I don't have any work to do in feature branch at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitbucket does not "know" about your newly created local branch, until you actually push it.  So try:

```
git push origin feature/profile
```

After pushing, it should show up in the list of active branches.

Note this is typical behavior for Git, which was created with the intention for it to be a highly distributed version control system.  That is, you may create a local branch, use it, etc., without the remote Bitbucket needing to know about this.

Comment: Thanks Tim Biegeleisen branch showing up after git push origin 'branch-name'. I didn't know that git push origin 'branch name' can work without having anything to push.